# I want to change my discord bot status from playing, to watching

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to have my status be "Watching" for command -help", but I don't know how to switch it from playing to watching,

Here is my code:

```
command(client, 'status', (message) => {
    if (message.author.id != "my id goes here") return;    
    const content = message.content.replace('-status ', '')

    client.user.setPresence({
        activity: {
            name: content,
            type: 0,
        },
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the code :

```
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online', //you can set online , idle , dnd and offline
        activity: {
            name: 'Some Name',
            type: 'PLAYING', //here you can change it to 'WATCHING' , 'PLAYING' , STREAM,
            url: 'https://discord.com'
        }
    });
```

For more info you can check [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData)